# javascript not defined even though i use it the line before?

Tags: javascript

```
console.debug("slide number");
console.debug(slideNumber)

console.debug("divs");
console.debug(imageIDDivs);
var singleimageidDiv = imageIdDivs[slideNumber];
```

This is a section of my javascript. In firebug this is the output.

```
slide number
Inspec...0001647 (line 49)
1
Inspec...0001647 (line 50)
divs
Inspec...0001647 (line 52)
[div#75bf9997-f111-4cbe-bee7-0765ba3bb8ca.slideshowImage, div#68c33349-cae6-4c2d-a9ed-1f87b12f06a2.slideshowImage, div#9e068363-6613-4346-b1e3-2ff4a3e2223b.slideshowImage, div#963a1d6a-a744-4a81-8608-5475b8fb21b1.slideshowImage, div#bd3f116d-9af9-4ca0-a45c-a366fd166ed0.slideshowImage, div#8ad2a764-14ab-466f-a614-a3676cca2127.slideshowImage, div#e99b579a-8e09-42e5-8951-b00613bc333a.slideshowImage, div#843ccfe7-5708-4794-b0dd-b10350277c64.slideshowImage, div#1e24f5f4-de3a-4b4f-b23d-b6ef9b513dad.slideshowImage, div#e862c867-5b93-4a3b-a235-b7bc0ac9cf37.slideshowImage, div#d99ca360-952d-46ff-9bda-bc87e13ef0a2.slideshowImage]
Inspec...0001647 (line 53)
imageIdDivs is not defined
```

It says that imageIdDivs is not defined. However in the line right above it, i output it just fine and it has a ton of divs in it. and slideNumber, as outputted before that, is just the number 1.
How is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`imageIDDivs` !== `imageIdDivs`

**javascript is case-sensitive!**

Comment: Thanks! i think it is time for a break... you have no idea how long i was staring at that block of code completely baffled

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case-sensitive. That means two variables that are not the **exact** same will considered different variables.

In your script you are referencing the variables `imageIDDivs` and `imageIdDivs`. The solution is to change `imageIdDivs` on line 53 to `imageIDDivs`.