# Variables not defined when access using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm stumped - I am trying to get variables from a typical drag and drop - they're showing fine in the `alert` I use to test, but the ajax tells me `droppedId` is undefined?

```
$( ".folder" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {

    var draggedId = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
    var droppedId = $(this).attr("folderid");

    alert ('dropped ' + draggedId + ' into folder ' + droppedId); // works ok

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: '/ajax/actions/dragLink.php?folder_id=' + droppedID + '&bm_id=' + draggedId,
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {

            $("#myAction").load('/ajax/actions/links.php?success=true&folder_id=' + data);

                        }

                    }); // End .ajax function

                }
            });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript not defined even though i use it the line before?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889953/javascript-not-defined-even-though-i-use-it-the-line-before)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case sensitive.

You need to use `droppedId`

```
url: '/ajax/actions/dragLink.php?folder_id=' + droppedId + '&bm_id=' + draggedId,
```

Notice it's `droppedId` and not `droppedID`

Comment: Schoolboy error or what! Thanks mate

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - no worries Daz!

Answer (score 0):

You have a case mismatch. You meant to type `droppedId`, not `droppedID`:

```
url: '/ajax/actions/dragLink.php?folder_id=' + droppedId + '&bm_id=' + draggedId
```

Javascript *is* case-sensitive.